# Angular and Ionic 6 Can't bind to '{ngModel}' error in console for ion-textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Angular 14 + Ionic 6 app where i have an ionic `<ion-textarea>` item. The app compiles corectly but in the browser console I keep getting this error:

> Can't bind to '{ngModel}' since it isn't a known property of
> 'ion-textarea' (used in the 'CartPage' component template).
>
> 1. If 'ion-textarea' is an Angular component and it has the '{ngModel}' input, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where
>    this component is declared.
> 2. If 'ion-textarea' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

I have looked at the documentation of both angular and ionic I I think I have done everything correctly.
I have included ionic, formsModule in my app.module.ts file. Just in case here is the whole app.module.ts file If I have missed something.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent,],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        SwiperModule,
        SharedModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    providers: [{provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}, {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'sl'}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [

    ]
})
```

what is weird to me is that I have used [{ngModel}] on  a few lines of code above the  and have not received this error message.

Any idea what could be the source of my problem?

Comment: Tried `[(ngModel)]` instead?

Comment: yeah ... `{ngModel`} is not a thing

Comment: @Pieterjan I can now confirm I need glasses :D haha omg how did I not see this